# Empty shouldComponentUpdate works, otherwise not?

Tags: reactjs

I really can't figured out why if I declare an empty `shouldComponentUpdate` in a component, like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {},
```

React automatically **doesn't render** the component when it's not necessary (and that's perfectly fine).

WHILE if I remove the empty declaration, it will render it every time...

I'm using Immutable.js for props.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs

> By default, shouldComponentUpdate **always returns true** to prevent subtle bugs when state is mutated in place [...]

If you override it with an empty function, it will return `undefined`, which is cast to `false`, therefore your component **never** re-renders (except in the case where a `forceUpdate` will force it to render without checking `shouldComponentUpdate`).

Answer (score 0):

Oscar is correct, you are getting an undefined. Try

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) { return true; },
```