# Is returning `true` in shouldComponentUpdate the same as not having shouldComponentUdpate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-lifecycle

In my React Native component, I added an empty `shouldComponentUpdate`

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        
}
```

I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180660/empty-shouldcomponentupdate-works-otherwise-not) answer that having an empty `shouldComponentUpdate` results in eliminating all unnecessary re-renders. If I return `true` in the body of `shouldComponentUpdate` though, will that be identical to removing `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: It wouldn’t eliminate “unnecessary” re-renders. AFAIK the default impl still returns true.

Comment: Please don't tag your titles.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of the method returns `true` which means in your case removing the `shouldComponentUpdate` will result in the same behavior.

https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action

[image]